# Window screen partially pixelated

Tags: windows-10, display, nvidia-geforce

Apologies if this is not the correct place for this question, but I'm a bit at a loss. My Windows suddenly started pixelating at random intervals as the following screenshot shows.

I believe this might be due to a possibly failed Geforce GTX1050 driver update, as I had a shoddy update before this started.

Some notes, it dissappears wherever I move the cursor around it, so it is dynamic, and I've only seen it on chrome (haven't tested this properly). I also have 2 screens, I've seen it on both, but only one at a time.

View of pixelated Chrome tab:

[image: View of pixelated Chrome tab]

Comment: That's not pixelation, that's severe graphical corruption.

Comment: Looks like graphics memory damage to me. Maybe also check your RAM while you’re at it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest driver from
[NVIDIA Driver Downloads](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)
and install it.
The option of "Automatically find drivers for my NVIDIA products" on the webpage,
if it works for you, can ensure getting the right driver.

If a new driver does not help, you may have a hardware problem
that requires repairs.
Check the connectors and reseat the card.
Try also another graphical card, before deciding that the old one is broken.
(That's just about the most we can advise with a hardware problem.)